# awk - no output after subtracting two matching columns in two files

Tags: awk

I'm learning `awk` and I'd like to use it to get the difference between two columns in two files

If an entry in `file_2 column-2` exists in `file_1 column-4`, I want to subtract `file_2 column-3` from of `file_1 column-2`

**file_1.txt**

```
chrom_1 1000    2000    gene_1
chrom_2 3000    4000    gene_2
chrom_3 5000    6000    gene_3
chrom_4 7000    8000    gene_4
```

**file_2.txt**

```
chrom_1 gene_1  114 252
chrom_9 gene_5  24  183
chrom_2 gene_2  117 269
```

Here's my code but I get no output:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{key[$1]=$4;file1col1[$1]=$2;next} $2 in key {print file1col1[$1]-$3}' file_1.txt file_2.txt
```

Comment: `key[$1]=$4` from file 1 would be better as `key[$4] = $2` -- that way the array, indexed by gene name holds the value for that gene from column 2.

Comment: This? `awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{key[$4]=$2;file1col1[$1]=$2;next} $2 in key {print file1col1[$1]-$3}' file_1.txt file_2.txt`. Still doesn't work

Comment: Spend time learning `awk`. It is by far the most capable Swiss Army-Knife of text processing. Every minute you spend learning will save you 10-fold later.

Comment: Good to know, I'll put in the work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close. But indexing `key` by the gene name storing the value from the 4th field will allow you to simply subtract `key[$2] - $3` to get your result, e.g.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {key[$4] = $2; next} $2 in key {print key[$2] - $3}' file1 file2
886
2883
```

(**note**: there is no `gene_5` so `key[gene_5]` is taken as `0`. The test `$2 in key` conditions the 2nd rule to only execute if the gene is present in `key`)

**Write the Rules Out**

Sometimes it helps to write the rules for the script out rather than trying to make a 1-liner out of the script. This allows for better readability. For example:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {                 # Rule1 conditioned by NR==FNR (file_1)
    key[$4] = $2            # Store value from field 2 indexed by field 4
    next                    # Skip to next record
  }
  $2 in key {               # Rule2 conditioned by $2 in key (file_2)
    print key[$2] - $3      # Output value from file_1 - field 3
  }
' file_1.txt file_2.txt
```

**Further Explanation**

`awk` will read each line of input (record) from the file(s) and it will apply each rule to the record in the order the rules appear. Here, when the record number equals the file record number (only true for file_1), the first rule is applied and then the `next` command tells `awk` to skip everything else and go read the next record.

Rule 2 is conditioned by `$2 in key` which tests whether the gene name from file 2 exists as an index in `key`. (the `value in array` test does not create a new element in the array -- this is a useful benefit of this test). If the gene name exists in the `key` array filled from file_1, then field 3 from file_2 is subtracted from that value and the difference is output.

One of the best refernces to use when learning `awk` is [Tje GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents). It provides an excellent reference for `awk` and any `gawk` only features are clearly marked with `'#'`.

Comment: Mine's printing file-2 column-3 with a negative sign instead. Let me figure this one out

Comment: If you are still stuck let me know or let me know exactly what you want the output to look like and I'm happy to help further. Sometimes it is easier to look at the *rules*. There are two rules. The first fills the `key` array, the second, only run for file2 subtracts file2 field 3 from file1 field 2.

Comment: Yes, @David I'm stuck. Especially since the above code produces a different output for me compared to yours.

The output I expect is just two lines showing

`886
2883`

Comment: No worries, I'll update. Are you sure you have tab-separated fields? It shouldn't matter as the default field separate breaks on whitespace (tab and space are both whitespace). You just need to add a check to avoid the zero value if there is no gene number in `key`. Let me know if the update is what you needed.

Comment: I'll forever be thankful because I'm not making progress with this part of my learning. 100% sure the files a tab-separated.

Comment: Okay, First, this is plain `awk` no special `gawk` features used. I have created your input files as `tab` separated (and multiple space separated). There isn't any difference. You can add `-v FS='\t' ` to the beginning, but it will make no difference. `value in array` ( `$2 in key` ) is a simple test that checks if the index `$2` in the 2nd file (the gene name) exists in `key` and only executes the 2nd rule if it does. You are providing the common field between file1 file2 (the gene) as the index in `key`. `key[$2] - $3` is the value from file1 less the value from file2 for those fields.

Comment: If you simply copy/paste what I have (adding `.txt` to the filenames) what output do you see? Your `-F'\t'` is fine, it is equivalent to `-v FS='\t'`.

Comment: Thanks, David for the solution and reference, finally, kindly elaborate on these two points

`key[$4] = $2` -> During my tutorials I thought it ought to be `key[$1]=$4` and this will create an array called `key` and assign the values of field 4

`print key[$2] - $3` *# Output value from file_1 - field 3* -> am losing track somewhere, how is the output of file_1 referenced with k[$2] and not k[$4]

Comment: Awk arrays are *associative* arrays (meaning not numerically indexed). What you want to do is provide a *Map* from file1 into file2. You do that trough the gene_X field. By using the array `key` with the index being the gene name, you store the value from file1 in that array element. Then in file2, the gene name is in field2 -- so when you reference `key[$2]` in file2, you may the value from file1 (because `key[gene_name]` will work in file2 just the same as in file1). You have the gene_name from file2, and value from file1 (`key[$2]`) so all you do is subtract `$3` and you have your value.

Comment: The key (no pun intended) is that indexing `key[]` by the gene name (`$4` in file1 and `$2` in file2), you can map the value from file1 to subtract the value from file2. Only one array is needed, not two. `key[gene_name]` holds the value from file1 for the gene_name (from file1 `$2`), and then using `key[$2]` in file2 -- you ensure the correct value is mapped for subtracting `$3`. That's why you fill `key[$4] = $2` in file` and then use `key[$2]` in file2 to retrieve the correct value `:)`

Comment: Think of it this way. From file1 you fill `key[]` with `key[gene_1] = 1000`, `key[gene_2] = 3000`, `key[gene_3] = 5000` and `key[gene_4] = 7000`. Now what fields do you use to get there in file1, and then what field do you need to use as an index from file2 to get the value back? That should also make clear why you condition rule2 with `$2 in key` to make sure there was a matching gene name for the index in the record from file2. Digest it a while and let me know if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks a million, @David, for taking the time and being so elaborate. A lot of what I've encountered so far is starting to make sense...

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your scripting. It takes a bit of work to make friends with `awk`, but once you realize it's a tool that reads each line for you and splits the line into fields based on the field-separator  -- then it's just up to you to write the rules to tell `awk` what to do with each line, it's not that bad. Here, the challenge was to look at the data in file1 and file2 and choose a common field from each you can use to map data from a record in file1 and use it with the corresponding record in file2. Not hard, but frustrating until the light-bulb winks on `:)`

Comment: Am starting to appreciate its utility in my field. I work on genomic data and most of my input is very well structured so awk is just one of the tools I need. Cheers

Comment: @K.Wamae itll also help you and others to understand your code if you name your variables based on what they really are. For example your array named `key[]` is NOT a key. The **index** used in the array could be considered a key but the array itself maps every key (aka `tag`, `name` or `gene`) to a value so a better name for your array would be `map[]`. The assignment `key[$4] = $2` is mapping a key (`$4`) to a value (`$2`)  and so should be `map[$4] = $2` (and of course `$2 in key` would then be `$2 in map`) and then any time you want to use that arrays indices **those** would be named `key`

Comment: Thanks, @EdMorton. I hadn't really understood arrays in awk, but after getting help with this problem, plus the explanation you provided....it has cleared up a lot of things. I'll be more careful with how I assign variable names going forward..